# wso2 how to sign a respond outbound message using ws-security policy?

Tags: wso2, ws-security

we have this flow
   client ----> secure proxy (esb) inbound --> proccess/insert message into database
  ......
    secure-proxy(esb) outbound ----(ack sign response) -------> client

A messages schema flow picture.
[image: messages flow]

The ack must go signed with a secure policy. This security policy is the same that inbound messages.

This is our proxy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="secure_proxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <header action="remove" name="wsse:Security" scope="default" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>

            <dbreport description="queryDataBase">
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <dsName>JNDI/NAME</dsName>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql><![CDATA[update TABLE SET PARAM1 =?, PARAM2=? WHERE CONDITION =? AND NUM=?]]></sql>
                    <parameter expression="get-property('PARAM1')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                    <parameter expression="get-property(//*[local-name()='PARAM2']" type="VARCHAR"/>
                    <parameter expression="get-property(//*[local-name()='CONDITION']" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <parameter expression="get-property(//*[local-name()='NUM'])" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </statement>
            </dbreport>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <ns:recepcionResponse xmlns:ns="http://es.ws">
                        <ns:return>200></ns:return>
                    </ns:recepcionResponse>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>

            <header name="wsse:Security" scope="default" value="" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>

           <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="***********************OUT" value="**********ACK_S002"/>
            </log>

            <send/>

        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log description="Error" level="custom">
                <property name="text" value="ERROR"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="ErrorMessage: "/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')" name="ErrorDetail: "/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')" name="Exception:"/>
            </log>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="https://URI?wsdl"/>
    <policy key="gov:ws-config/policy.xml"/>
    <enableSec/>
</proxy>
```

We receive messages which was signed using this OSB sec policy

```
<WL5G3N0:definitions xmlns:WL5G3N0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://es.xyz" xmlns:WL5G3N4="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:WL5G3N5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" targetNamespace="http://es.xyz">
<WL5G3N0:documentation>Policy</WL5G3N0:documentation>
<WL5G3N1:Policy WL5G3N2:Id="Sign.xml">
<wssp:Integrity xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy/wsee#part" xmlns:wssp="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wssp:SignatureAlgorithm URI="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<wssp:CanonicalizationAlgorithm URI="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<wssp:Target>
<wssp:DigestAlgorithm URI="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<wssp:MessageParts Dialect="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy/wsee#part">wls:SystemHeaders()</wssp:MessageParts>
</wssp:Target>
<wssp:Target>
<wssp:DigestAlgorithm URI="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<wssp:MessageParts Dialect="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy/wsee#part">wls:SecurityHeader(wsu:Timestamp)</wssp:MessageParts>
</wssp:Target>
<wssp:Target>
<wssp:DigestAlgorithm URI="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<wssp:MessageParts Dialect="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/2002/12/wsse#part">wsp:Body()</wssp:MessageParts>
</wssp:Target>
<wssp:SupportedTokens>
<wssp:SecurityToken IncludeInMessage="true" TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
<wssp:TokenIssuer>
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</wssp:TokenIssuer>
</wssp:SecurityToken>
</wssp:SupportedTokens>
</wssp:Integrity>
<wssp:MessageAge xmlns:wssp="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy" Age="60"/>
</WL5G3N1:Policy>
```

This is our sec policy. We have to respond using this sec policy to send outbound messages.

```
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>                                   
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                    <!-- sp:WssX509V3Token10/ -->
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>                                    
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                    <!-- sp:WssX509V3Token10/ -->
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:ProtectTokens/>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss10>
            <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>     
    <rampart:RampartConfig xmlns:rampart="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
            <rampart:user>my_private_key</rampart:user>
            <rampart:encryptionUser>your_public_key</rampart:encryptionUser>
            <rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>true</rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>
            <rampart:timestampTTL>300</rampart:timestampTTL>
            <rampart:timestampMaxSkew>300</rampart:timestampMaxSkew>
            <rampart:timestampStrict>false</rampart:timestampStrict>
            <rampart:passwordCallbackClass>es.example.wso2.PWCBHandler</rampart:passwordCallbackClass>
            <rampart:tokenStoreClass>org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore</rampart:tokenStoreClass>
            <rampart:nonceLifeTime>300</rampart:nonceLifeTime>
            <rampart:encryptionCrypto>
                <rampart:crypto cryptoKey="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore" provider="org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto">
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.alias">your_public_key</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">test.jks</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.stratos.tenant.id">-1234</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.truststores">test.jks</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="rampart.config.user">your_public_key</rampart:property>
                </rampart:crypto>
            </rampart:encryptionCrypto>
            <rampart:signatureCrypto>
                <rampart:crypto cryptoKey="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore" provider="org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto">
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.alias">my_private_key</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">test.jks</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.stratos.tenant.id">-1234</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.truststores">test.jks</rampart:property>
                    <rampart:property name="rampart.config.user">my_private_key</rampart:property>
                </rampart:crypto>
            </rampart:signatureCrypto>

        </rampart:RampartConfig>
</wsp:Policy>
```

How do we can this? anyhelp will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your sec. policy file as well? (ok, strip the passwords :P) The policy file is applied by default (until not specified otherwise) to both request and response.

Comment: yes, i'll edit the question including sec policy.

Comment: i've just attached an image with the messages flow. First at all, system inside send a msg01 through esb to the system outside. Msg01 have to go signed. System outside proccess message and send a signed request (msg02), proxy_service2 have to proccess the msg02 and if it is right, sends a custom signed response to system outside.

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: As a priority I need to finish my work tasks and test / answer once having some spare time (if any) .. :/

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am very grateful for your help, now i am into a dead point.

Answer (score 0):

Hasn't this sample[1] helped in achieving your flow. At [2], you can find a policy that does both signing and encryption for the outgoing message which you can adjust removing encryption part if not needed and refer to it from proxy service definition.()

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Sample+100%3A+Using+WS-Security+for+Outgoing+Messages

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/blob/v6.0.0/samples/product/src/main/conf/synapse/resources/policy/policy_3.xml

Comment: yes, i've followed this sample for inbound messages. In this case and me, we have to receive signed messages following a sec policy. But in our case we have to send a signed response using the out sequence. In the sample, the out sequence send a message without security.

Comment: you can full flow in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working policy I had from some past https://pastebin.com/0s2DzPn5

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SigOnly"
   xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                   sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                   sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss10>
            <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <rampart:RampartConfig xmlns:rampart="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
        <rampart:user>wso2carbon</rampart:user>
        <rampart:passwordCallbackClass>com.apogado.wso2egov.passwordcallback.SimplePasswordCallback</rampart:passwordCallbackClass>
        <rampart:signatureCrypto>
            <rampart:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin" cryptoKey="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file" cacheRefreshInterval="300000">
                <rampart:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</rampart:property>
                <rampart:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</rampart:property>
                <rampart:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">wso2carbon</rampart:property>
            </rampart:crypto>
        </rampart:signatureCrypto>
        <rampart:encryptionCypto>
            <rampart:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin" cryptoKey="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file" cacheRefreshInterval="300000">
                <rampart:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</rampart:property>
                <rampart:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</rampart:property>
                <rampart:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">dkkdkvdt123</rampart:property>
            </rampart:crypto>
        </rampart:encryptionCypto>
    </rampart:RampartConfig>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Please note this will include the subject identifier as a token in the response not the whole certificate (binary token) but once you have it working, you can play with the options

this is another of mine policies used: https://pastebin.com/9iYL5TCj

Comment: i do not understood one thing.  In the first part of the dialog the policy has run right, when the system inside sends a message to system outside through in sequence. Why doesnt work in the other case, system outside sends message, in sequence receive it and proccess it, then respond out sequence with the result. The prixy service has not an endpoint defined

Comment: The proxy service (the same case as yours) has a <loopback /> element effectively processing the outSequence, so no endpoint is needed (ther's no external endpoint)

Comment: And for the policy itself - I have to admin - most of it I take from existing templates and then using trial/error approach I made it work (and I am truly afraid most of people work with ws-policy this way)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. i get it. I only had to change the recipient policy to ..../IncludeToken/always, then proxy service included the binary token that i needed. All it is ok and the proxy service is working right. Now I trying to  install into EIS 6.0